# (Measure theory) Convergence under integral sign of a decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am stuck with the following problem. **The problem is still unsolved.**

Let $\left(X,\mu\right)$ be a measure space with a **positive, finite 
measure** $\mu$; and let $\left\{ f_{j}\in L^{\infty}\left(X\right)\right\}$ 
be a decreasing sequence converging pointwise to $f;$ $f_{j}\searrow f.$
Assume that 
$$
\intop_{X}f_{j}d\mu\geq-1.
$$
 Can we conclude that 
$$
\intop_{X}fd\mu\geq-1?
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Do you assume that $f_j \in L_1$ ... or would you allow $\int f_j\;d\mu = +\infty$ for all $j$ ?  In that case you could have $\int f\;d\mu < -1$.

Comment: Hi, I assume the measure is finite, which I forgot to add in. Since $\mu(X)<\infty$, it implies that each $f_{j}\in L^{1}$. Thank.

Comment: Now also asked on MO: [Monotone convergence of a integral under a decreasing sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300100).

Comment: Finiteness of the measure is an important assumption. Without that you can give an example where $\int f$ is not even defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true at all. For instance, consider $f_j(x)=-2X_{[0,j]}+2jX_{[j,j+1]}$. Then the integral of $f_j$ equals 0, whereas its pointwise limit is $f(x)=-2$, which is not even Lebesgue integrable. Of course, if you need $f$ to be integrable, you can still show that this still doesn't hold by taking $f_j(x)=-\Sigma_{k=0}^{j-1}2^{-j}+2X_{[j,j+1]}$, whose pointwise limit is $f(x)=-\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty 2^{1-j}X_{[j,j+1]}$, boasting an integral of -2.

Edit: I didn't notice the requirement that $f_j$ be decreasing. The given claim does hold - just apply the dominated convergence theorem for $\max{|f_1|,|f|}$ as the dominating function.

Comment: It seems that the sequence in your example is not decreasing.

Comment: Oh, that is accurate. Do excuse my lack of attention.